# Захват с микрофона звука со сжатием

Tags: flash, actionscript

Есть примерно такой код(лишнее вырезано):

```
soundData = new ByteArray();
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
microphone.rate = 8;
microphone.gain = 100;
microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);

function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void {
  while (event.data.bytesAvailable) {
    var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
    soundData.writeFloat(sample);
  }
}
```

В этом случае, в массив soundData записывается звук принимаемый микрофоном, без сжатия (WAVE по сути).
Как бы сделать так, чтобы записывать в ByteArray звук после сжатия кодеком SPEEX.
То есть, тот поток, который используется, например при передаче через FMS или p2p.